# Django migrations integrity error column contains null values

Tags: django

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "required_tem_grid" contains null values
```

So I mistakenly gave wrong type of value when Django asked me to provide default value for existing rows. Problem is now that I am stuck with this error. I have been burned by this error before too and the only way I could recover was to create another db and running migrations again. Is there any other way? I have tried to revert to previous migration (initial) but this error pops up everywhere. There is no such column in the database that I can see. Is there some place this default value gets cached?

Comment: There must be a migrations that has been created for this change in your models, you can edit that. There you can find the column `required_tem_grid` and change the default value. However keep in mind that you may need to drop your DB and create that again. Also you can delete the last migration you made that had these changes and change the default value inside your models, create the migration again and migrate. This would too require the DB to be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it this way: Delete migration files and cached files, remove offending entry from models, delete migration data from `django_migrations` table for the app, run `makemigrations` and `migrate --fake-initial`. I was then able to change models and run migrations.